# Enable cache mechanism for entire application based on flag from properties file

Tags: spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, spring-cache

I want to enable/disable spring boot( redis )cache based on the flag set in the properties file.

Suppose I set cacheEnabled=true in the properties file then it should not consider cache mechanism for entire application
Use Case:I have different client and some may have cache mechanism and some does not..So I just need to set caching based on the flag in the properties file without touching code..(properties file i can read externally)

I tried conditional SPEL based on the flag set from properties but it appear to be only on method..when i use @EnableCaching at main class and @cachable then application started but when i trigger request its saying connection refused..

I just need to use redis for my application and keep all the code as is..and based on the flag without touching any code..i need to enable or disable cache mechanism..Can anyone help me on this please.

Comment: `spring.cache.mode=none` disables caching. Well it will still add caching but registers a NOOP cache, so effectivly no cache.

Comment: thank you for the info Deinum..but i did not see any spring config with spring.cache.mode..im using spring boot 2.7.5 and redis 3.1.6 version.I think its spring.cache.type-none(i refer, one of your other post)..

Comment: Ahyes properties change and I should have looked at the list.